# Undefined reference in opencv program

Tags: c++, c, opencv, computer-vision

I have kubuntu and i've installed Opencv with the instruction

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

on Kubuntu 13.04. 
I try to compile a program on opencv but i have this error:

```
berny88@berny88-VPCEB3J1E:~/Scaricati/CameraCalibration/camera_calibration/camera_calibration$ g++ -Iusr/include/opencv2  camera_calibration.cpp 
/tmp/cc51xq2l.o: In function `main':
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `cvCreateCameraCapture'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x1d2): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x225): undefined reference to `cvFindChessboardCorners'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `cvFindCornerSubPix'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x2fa): undefined reference to `cvDrawChessboardCorners'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x61e): undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x628): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x682): undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x69d): undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x6bb): undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x6dd): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x6f9): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0x711): undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xba8): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xbb7): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xbc6): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xc78): undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xcbc): undefined reference to `cvCalibrateCamera2'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xd41): undefined reference to `cvSave'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xdb2): undefined reference to `cvSave'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xde4): undefined reference to `cvLoad'
camera_calibration.cpp:(.text+0xe01): undefined reference to `cvLoad'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can resolve this problem??

Comment: what does your makefile/link options look like?

Comment: there isn't make file. But i don't see where is the library! I see the include file but  i don't know where is the library

Comment: Compile with `g++ -Iusr/include/opencv2  camera_calibration.cpp $(pkg-config opencv --libs)`